# ProgressDialog Dismiss and AlertDialogShow if there isn't a internetConnection

Tags: android, progressdialog, android-alertdialog, internet-connection

I am using a web service for my application.The data are fatcing in the method callWebService().I am showing ProgressDialog while populating my ListView.Also I like to check  if there isnt a network connection to dismiss the ProgressDialog and to show AlertDialog to the user.Could somebody help me here is my code

```
     myProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(ExchangeMoneMK1Activity.this,
                     "Please wait...", "Loading...", true);
         Thread thread = new Thread(this);
         thread.start();


 private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
          = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null;
}




private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch(msg.what){
        case 0:

            myProgressDialog.dismiss();
            int resID = R.layout.list_item;
            aa = new ExchangeRateAdapter(ExchangeMoneMK1Activity.this, resID,currencyList);

            lw.setAdapter(aa);
            break;
        }


    }
```

};

```
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try {
        if(isNetworkAvailable())
        callWebService();
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }


     catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I don't have alertdialog yet because if there isn't a internet connection the progress bar isn't dismissing
I have put in the AndroidManifest priviledge

Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

use finally also with try catch and put handler.sendEmptyMessage(0); in finnaly...

as I think you are getting the any excption and your flow jumps to catch from callWebService()..... and not reaching to handler.sendEmptyMessage(0); line........

Answer (score 0):

Use AsyncTask. It will be much simpler. The general pattern is as follows. There may be a few minor compile errors, but, this will give you an idea.

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList> {
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ArrayList currencyList;
        if(isNetworkAvailable())
            currencyList = callWebService();
        return currencyList;
    }
    void onPreExecute() {
        myProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(ExchangeMoneMK1Activity.this,
                 "Please wait...", "Loading...", true);
    }
    void onPostExecute(ArrayList currencyList) {
        myProgressDialog.dismiss();
        if (currencyList == null) {
            //Handle error
            return;
        }
        int resID = R.layout.list_item;
        aa = new ExchangeRateAdapter(ExchangeMoneMK1Activity.this, resID,currencyList);

        lw.setAdapter(aa);
    }
}
```